# Can you get (using jQuery if possible) the current scrolled position of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code on a 'down' button to scroll text in an overflowed div.

```
var textHeight = text.outerHeight();
var pageDown = $('#page-down');
var pageUp = $('#page-up');

pageDown.bind('click', function () {
    pageUp.fadeIn(500);
    text.animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + textHeight + 'px' }, 500);
});
```

This is working nicely, but I need a method to determine when the scroll down button should disappear ... i.e. when the last content has appeared inside the div.

Is there a property or method to get the scrolled position within that div? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple links you may want to look at:

http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/

http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg22400.html

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid... this returns a number I can use:

```
    console.log($('#text').attr('scrollTop'));
```

Comment: alternatively use jQuery's built in $('#text').scrollTop()